# Ansible cannot read attribute by XPath (not element)

Tags: xml, xpath, ansible

I am trying to read an XML attribute's value from an XML file but I get this error:

> Xpath /sca:composite/@revision does not reference a node!

My XML file looks like:

```xml
<composite revision="1.0.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/1.0">
  ...
</composite>
```

And my Ansible command is:

```yaml
- name: 'Get revision'
  xml:
    path: 'composite.xml'
    xpath: '/sca:composite/@revision'
    content: attribute
    namespaces:
      sca: 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/1.0'
  register: my_revision
```

I have tried no less than 20 permutations of XPath, such as:

```
/composite/@revision
/composite/revision
/sca:composite/@revision
/sca:composite/revision
/sca:composite/@sca:revision
```

And with **content** as both **text** and **attribute**.

The closest I can come is to match on the root node with XPath: `/sca:composite`.

But I just can't find the attribute.
Any tips?

Comment: I see that the documentation says "This module does not handle complicated xpath expressions, so limit xpath selectors to simple expressions." My tip is that if that's what the documentation is like, I wouldn't touch the product with a barge-pole.

Comment: Most likely `@revision` should also be namespaced. But without a [mre], this is impossible for us to give you a definitive answer. Please provide a **complete** XML containing all the elements you are trying to match with your Path expression.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε  We don't have control over the schema of composite.xml (it's an Oracle artifact).  However, I figured out a workaround that involves only evaluating the element in XPath and then navigating to the attribute in the JSON matches array (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

I found a hokey 2-step workaround.  First, XPath match on just the element.  Second, navigate the JSON results/matches for the attribute.

```yaml
- name: 'Match XPath'
  xml:
    path: 'composite.xml'
    xpath: '/sca:composite'
    content: attribute
    namespaces:
      sca: 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/1.0'
  register: xpath_match

- name: 'Get revision'
  set_fact:
    my_revision: '{{xpath_match.matches[0]["{http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/1.0}composite"].revision}}'
```

NOTE: The XPath match returned a JSON object like:

```json
{
  "matches": [
    {
      "{http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/1.0}composite": {
        "revision": "1.0.1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Don't get confused about the JSON field name for `"composite"`.  It's syntax is `"{xmlnamespace}composite"`